# OEM driver not available for Galaxy S5?

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-drivers, developer-options

I followed [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html) document and it gave me [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads) link to Samsung's website to download the OEM driver for my Samsung Galaxy S5.

However, I couldn't find its model in the list. My phone's model is SM-G900F as shown here:
[image: img]

The list contains many similar models such as SM-G900A but not exactly my model.

Where can I find the OEM USB drivers for my phone? My goal is to debug using a physical device in Android Studio.

Comment: @beeshyams I checked the site linked to by the XDA post and all devices share the same piece of driver. I wonder who designed the page...

Comment: @AndyYan:: thanks for checking.. Ridiculous.. Am deleting the earlier link

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are usually *not* device-specific - manufacturers package drivers for most if not all their devices in one package for installation. In Samsung's case, it's called **Samsung USB Drivers for Mobile Phones**. It's up to you to Google and find the latest version, although someone has some hosted at [OdinDrivers](http://www.odindrivers.net/) (external site - safety not guaranteed).